# How to Fix Incomplete Network Tab Display Issue in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Has anyone else experienced the issue where the last line in Chrome's network tab is partially hidden and requires clicking to view the entire line? If so, are there any known solutions or workarounds to fix this problem?

[ChromeScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp76l.png)

I've attempted to scroll all the way down, but it seems I cannot access the last line fully. When I click on it, a details window appears, and that's when I can view the complete content.